# Uploading a PDF file from Fiddler to a WebAPI method results in 415 Unsupported Media Type

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, pdf, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to upload a PDF file to my WebAPI method but I am receiving a 415 Unsupported Media Type error.  Do I need to put something specific in my WebApiConfig.cs file to allow for a PDF formatter?

Here's the signature for my controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage SavePdf(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            string fileLocation = @"\\server\shared\appname\";
            ...
```

My WebAPI is currently hosted on `localhost`.  I'm calling this WebAPI method from Fiddler.  Here's the "Composer" tab of Fiddler (I then click the blue Upload File link to upload my PDF):

[image]

Here's the resulting HTTP 415 error in Fiddler:

[image]

My gut feeling is I need to somehow tell my WebAPI to accept the PDF media type (application/pdf) but I'm not sure... any ideas?

Comment: How are you reading the request content in Web Api controller? Check this artcile: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/sending-html-form-data,-part-2

Comment: @KiranChalla It never even gets to the entry point of `SavePdf` - I have a breakpoint set at the first curly brace, so to answer your question, it never even gets to that point.  That's why my gut feeling is I need to add something to WebApiConfig.cs, but I'm sure.

Comment: Oh wait..Do not use `HttpPostedFileBase`..this is used in MVC..instead just do not have any parameter and just follow the article i mentioned above.

Comment: @KiranChalla Then how would I get the file name from the uploaded file to use in my code that will save this file to a share?

Comment: Can any one plz help me here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31339278/how-to-post-a-file-using-fiddler-to-webapi-using-c

Answer (score 3):

This means that the File format is not the expected media format configured in your `global.asax`:

```
var config = System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;
config.Formatters.Insert(0, new System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
```

You can 2 things, one is to implement your meadia format to accept files or you can tweak one Controller to accept them like this:

```
public class UploadController : ApiController
{
    public async Task < HttpResponseMessage > PostFormData() 
    {
        var root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
        var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);

        try 
        {
            // Read the form data.
            await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

            // Show all the key-value pairs.
            foreach(var key in provider.FormData.AllKeys) 
            {
                foreach(var val in provider.FormData.GetValues(key)) 
                {
                    var keyValue = string.Format("{0}: {1}", key, val);
                }
            }

            foreach(MultipartFileData fileData in provider.FileData) 
            {
                var fileName = fileData.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName;
            }
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e);
        }
    }
}
...
```

You can read more about it here:

- http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/sending-html-form-data,-part-2
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/559378/Implementing-Custom-Media-Formatters-in-ASP-NET-We

Answer (score 3):

You can just follow this article below:
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/sending-html-form-data,-part-2

Do not use `HttpPostedFileBase` as a parameter as Web API tries to model bind the request content using formatters present in the configuration...Web API doesn't have a formatter for multipart internally...you would need to read multipart request content in specific way...also `HttpPostedFileBase` from MVC.

Regarding the file name, you can take a look at this line `file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName` in the above article.