# How to Post a file using Fiddler to WebAPI using C#?

Tags: file-upload, asp.net-web-api, fiddler

I am new to `ASP.NET Web API`. I have a sample `FileUpload` `web api` (from some site) to upload files to the server. **But, don't know how to test it using Fiddler.**

http://localhost:54208/myapi/api/webapi/FileUpload

On test.aspx page: **Following works fine. 
I want to know how to use this API using Fiddler?**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="http://localhost:54208/myapi/api/webapi/FileUpload" id="ajaxUploadForm" novalidate="novalidate">

            <fieldset>
                <legend>Upload Form</legend>
                <ol>
                    <li>
                        <label>Description </label>
                        <input type="text" style="width:317px" name="description" id="description">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label>upload </label>
                        <input type="file" id="fileInput" name="fileInput" multiple>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="submit" value="Upload" id="ajaxUploadButton" class="btn">
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </fieldset>
        </form>

</body>
</html>


public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> FileUpload()
       {
           // Check whether the POST operation is MultiPart?
           if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
           {
               throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
           }

           // Prepare CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider in which our multipart form
           // data will be loaded.
           //string fileSaveLocation = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
           string fileSaveLocation = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles");
           CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider provider = new CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(fileSaveLocation);
           List<string> files = new List<string>();

           try
           {
               // Read all contents of multipart message into CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider.
               await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

               foreach (MultipartFileData file in provider.FileData)
               {
                   files.Add(Path.GetFileName(file.LocalFileName));
               }

               // Send OK Response along with saved file names to the client.
               return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, files);
           }
           catch (System.Exception e)
           {
               return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e);
           }
       }
       // We implement MultipartFormDataStreamProvider to override the filename of File which
       // will be stored on server, or else the default name will be of the format like Body-
       // Part_{GUID}. In the following implementation we simply get the FileName from 
       // ContentDisposition Header of the Request Body.
       public class CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider : MultipartFormDataStreamProvider
       {
           public CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(string path) : base(path) { }

           public override string GetLocalFileName(HttpContentHeaders headers)
           {
               return headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Replace("\"", string.Empty);
           }
       }
```

Help Appreciated!

Comment: The simplest way to do this would be to capture the traffic from running your page once, then drag/drop that Session from Fiddler's Web Sessions list to the COMPOSER tab and modify it as desired.

Comment: ok I will try...! one more thing..is it possible to pass parameter to he method along with posting the file? as public void ([FromBody] string token) something like?

Comment: FromBody means that you have a value for the named parameter inside the body of the post.

Answer (score 1):

Go to fiddler, select post type, give your local web api url.
In request body just upload file and execute, it will go to webapi method directly.
Controller method should be `[HttpPost]`