# Sending byte array to API

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, fiddler

I am converting web application to mobile app. We were using `AjaxAsyncFileUpload` in  web application to save a document to the server, where `AjaxAsyncFileUpload` use to do the work for me. This was the code

```cs
Dim fileData As Byte() =new Byte(AjaxAsyncFileUpload.FileContent.Length-1){}
AjaxAsyncFileUpload.FileContent.Read(fileData, 0, fileData.Length)

InvestmentDeclare.DocSize  = AjaxAsyncFileUpload.FileContent.Length
InvestmentDeclare.DocFileName = AjaxAsyncFileUpload.FileName
InvestmentDeclare.DocFileType = AjaxAsyncFileUpload.PostedFile.ContentType
InvestmentDeclare.Document = fileData
```

And then simply save this to my database.

Now while Converting this to mobile app (I am also using c# for mobile app), I am not able to pass the byte array. I am using fiddler for testing.
I have attached an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQWGu.png) of how I'm passing it through fiddler. In my API POST method I'm getting a null value to my document variable while I'm able to get rest of my values properly.

What could be the issue? Am I not passing the byte in proper Json format?

In API:

```cs
public class AddInvestmentDeclare
{
 public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
 public int YearId { get; set; }
 public int InvestmentId { get; set; }
 public List<EmpDocument> EmpDocuments { get; set; }
}

public class EmpDocument
{
 public byte[] Document { get; set; }
 public string DocumentFileName { get; set; }
 public long DocumentSize { get; set; }
 public string DocumentType { get; set; }
}

public HttpResponseMessage Post(int YearId, [FromBody]List<AddInvestmentDeclare> InvestmentDeclared)
{
```

When I check my `InvestDeclared` list on run time I see that document variable is not filled and it is showing null. I have attached an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGgBA.png) of that as well.

Comment: Anyone who can help me with this please?

Comment: What is the application that is actually calling the post method? Show *that* code please. Fiddler is good for testing and to properly upload a file use https://stackoverflow.com/a/51622705/1260204. To read that file in, if it is passed correctly, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10320232/how-to-accept-a-file-post.

Comment: Have you tried sending the byte array as string?
I've found some example that I used for testing and the JSON that I'm using looks like this:
{
"ID":46,
"Content":"JVBERi0xLjQNCjEgMCBvYm......"
}

Also, try converting it with this https://stackoverflow.com/a/11654825/9233618

Comment: Also, why don't you set up API method in a way that it accepts just one object containing all data, instead of each parameter individually?

Comment: @Matt : Yes of course i can do that.

Comment: @TausifKhan Any success?

Comment: @Matt : Yes Matt. As you said combine it all in one object and so i did. I combined it all in one object and passed it through a POST method. And about my issue, I converted the file into base64 string and on my end i converted it back to byte[] array. Which worked for me. Thanks Matt.

Comment: @TausifKhan I will write it down as an answer so it is visible to others. I would appreciate if you would accept it as solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, setup your API method in a way that it accepts just one object containing all data instead of each parameter individually.

Instead of:

```cs
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromUri]string AccordDbName, [FromUri]String PayCareDbName, [FromUri]...)
```

Set it up like:

```cs
public HttpResponseMessage Post(Data dataObject)
```

Secondly, try sending file as a base64string.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11654562/how-convert-byte-array-to-string/11654825#11654825) is example how to do it.

Your file in JSON request should look something like this:

```json
{ "ID":46, 
  "Content":"JVBERi0xLjQNCjEgMCBvYm......"
}
```